# How bring selected choices to the next question with their embedded values for further evaluation?

Tags: qualtrics

I have a different attributes like

```
Select any one of the attributes given below:

A
B 
C
```

These attributes has to be selected by the participants for further decision making. If A and B are selected, I need to show A and B along with their embedded data in a table format automatically in Qualtrics.

Imagine if A and B is selected out of the 3 attributes, I need to show it like the table below automatically for participants evaluation.

````
A   50    80
B   40    30
```

Further if they select only C, C has to be displayed but not A and B.

```
C  90   100
```

I wish to do it in Qualtrics.
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working around with the Qualtrics platform. Use HTML and Javascript to complete the task.

Embed the data first into qualtrics - both the values for A and B and also if A is choosen assign a value to it.

Later, call the data based on conditions using HTML and Javascript. Load them into the question.

However, there is problem in aligning the variable values as a table in Qualtrics. But it is possible overcome it.